# CoCreateInstance C++/CLI class from Native C++

Tags: c++-cli, manifest, atl, regfreecom

I have declared C++/CLI class as below

```
namespace testcominterface {

  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("FFCA805F-8DAB-4AF8-A7B7-B488136E8177")]
  public interface class ITestInterface
  {
      public :
          void TestMethod();
  };


  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("E65F4772-54B5-4105-83E5-DCED24ABC815")]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType::AutoDual)]
  [ComDefaultInterface(ITestInterface::typeid)]       
  public ref class testCoClass : ITestInterface
  {
      public:
          virtual void TestMethod()
                {

                    Console::WriteLine("testCoClass::TestMethod : Test method");

                }
  };
 }
```

And I want to create the "testCoClass" through native C++ COM (by #import the TLB file and use CoCreateInstance) I always get an error "Class Not Registered". If I use "Regasm.exe" to register the assembly it works fine, but I don't want to register the assembly.

I have followed the steps in this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cheller/archive/2006/08/24/how-to-embed-a-manifest-in-an-assembly-let-me-count-the-ways.aspx to embedded manifest into the Assembly, but it didn't work.
(Note that this method always works with C# assembly, but this is a C++/CLI assembly.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A COM server needs to be registered so that COM can find the DLL when a client program asks for it.  Technically it can be avoided by giving the client program a manifest with reg-free COM entries, `<clrClass>` is required for COM servers that are written with managed code.  Key point is that this manifest needs to be embedded in the *client*, not the server.  Don't go there yet until you've got your COM server working properly.

One standard mistake is forgetting to use the /codebase option with Regasm.exe.  Without it, the assembly needs to be strong-named and put in the GAC.  This is not something you want to do on your dev machine.  Another common mistake is using the wrong version of Regasm.exe.  You'll need to pay attention to the bitness on a 64-bit machine.  And pick the right one if you use VS2010 and use the GAC, .NET 4 has a different location for the GAC.

You ought to improve the attributes you use.  A proper COM server only exposes the interfaces and hides the implementation.  Use [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType::InterfaceIsDual)] on the interface declaration and  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType::None)] on the class.  You now also no longer need [ComDefaultInterface] and the type library dependency on mscorlib.tlb will be gone.

If you still have trouble then SysInternals' ProcMon utility can show you exactly where in the registry the client looked for your server and compare it against the actual registry locations that your server uses.

Comment: I fixed the attributes of the interface and the class as your suggestions. I had the <clrclass in the manifest file of my COM Server. Although I'm not quite sure what is supposed to be in the Client manifest file. I put this `<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" type="win32" processorArchitecture="msil" name="testcominterface"></assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>`

I still got the same error.

Comment: There's no point in putting anything in the manifest of the server.  Windows can't read it until the server DLL is found first.  The egg goes before the chicken, it is the *client* that needs the manifest.  Again, don't go there until your server is working properly, debug one problem at a time.

Comment: I just got it to work by configuring my client vcxproj project to not embedded the manifest file. Then I manually created myclient.exe.manifest, with `<dependentAssembly>` reference to the COM Server assembly name. Then I had to create myclient.exe.config with ` <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">`

Comment: How can I avoid putting ` <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">` to my application config file? 

Again Thank you for your answer.

Comment: By targeting .NET 4 in your C++/CLI project.  Using a [ComVisible] server written in managed code from a managed client makes very little sense.  Just add a reference to the DLL itself so you use the managed class directly without going through COM.  This normally produces a loud complaint from the IDE when you try to add the type library reference, pretty unclear how you managed to avoid it.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear that my COM Client is Native C++.

I still don't know why I got an error saying that "Rejecting IJW module built against v2.0.50727 because it could be loaded into another runtime in this process". So I googled around and see the suggestion that I should add "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" to  myclient.exe.config. And it just works.

Adding reference to the managed DLL will block my app to run when no .NET installed on some machines.